# Single sample rendering into multisample attachment using Metal

Tags: macos, metal

I'm doing multi-sample (anti-aliasing) rendering using Metal/`MTKView`. This works fine, but I now want to draw a grid before rendering the actual content. The grid should not have anti-aliasing, to avoid grid lines being smeared over two pixels. When I set `sampleCount` to 1 on the pipeline I get the error that the `sampleCount` must match the sample count of the render target textures.

How can I first draw content with `sampleCount=1` and then continue drawing with `sampleCount=4`?